# Passing Python functions to Gnuplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, gnuplot

Plotting a Python function in Gnuplot is not straightforward although there
are some solutions. For example, one could either cast its values into an array or
manually translate its expression into Gnuplot’s syntax. Here is an
example that uses the module [`Gnuplot.py`](http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/) as an interface:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Gnuplot
import numpy as np

## define function ##
func = lambda x, x0, y0, w: y0 * np.exp( -4*np.log(2) * ( (x-x0) / w )**2 )
# also works with a regular function:
# def func(x, x0, y0, w):
    # return y0 * np.exp( -4*np.log(2) * ( (x-x0) / w )**2 )
popt = (10.1, 5, 2)

## linspace ##
x = np.linspace(0, 20, num=1000) # (x min, x max, number of points)
y = func(x, *popt)
func_linspace = Gnuplot.Data(x, y, with_='lines', title='linspace')

## expression “translation” (lambda only) ##
func_translation = Gnuplot.Func(
    '{y0} * exp( -4*log(2) * ( (x-{x0}) / {w} )**2 )'.format(
        x0=popt[0],
        y0=popt[1],
        w=popt[2],
        ),
    title='expression translation')

## plot ##
g = Gnuplot.Gnuplot()
g.plot(func_linspace, func_translation)
```

The first method works fine with a decent number of points but fails when
zooming-in too much or changing the window out of the array’s limits, while the
second one works at any zoom level. To illustrate this point, let’s zoom-in the
output of the previous script:

[image: function sampling vs expression translation]

For this reason, it would be interesting to find a way to plot Python functions
(lambda or regular functions) as **Gnuplot functions**. I can think of two
solution: automatically translating the expression (works only for “simple”
lambda functions”), or having Gnuplot directly use the Python function.

### First solution: expression translation (simple lambda functions only)

This method would not only be tricky to automate, it would also be impossible
to implement with elaborate functions. However we could still use this method
for simple lambda functions. To sketch the behaviour of an implementation:

```
>>> def lambda_to_gnuplot(func, popt):
...     # determine if translation is possible
...     # extract function expression and replace parameters with values
...     return func_expression # str
>>> lambda_to_gnuplot(
...     lambda x, x0, y0, w: y0 * np.exp( -4*np.log(2) * ( (x-x0) / w )**2),
...     (10.1, 5, 2))
'5 * exp( -4*log(2) * ( (x-10.1) / 2 )**2 )'
```

*Would there be a way to implement this `lambda_to_gnuplot` function in python?*

### Second solution: directly passing the Python function to Gnuplot

The “perfect” solution would be having Gnuplot use the Python function. In my
most daring dreams, it is something like:

```
>>> def func(x, x0, y0, w):
...     if x < x0:
...         return 0
...     else:
...         return y0 * np.exp( -4*np.log(2) * ( (x-x0) / w )**2)
>>> func_direct = Gnuplot.PyFunction(lambda x: func(x, 10.1, 5, 2))
>>> g.plot(func_direct)
```

This is the easiest solution to use, but its implementation would be very
tough, if not impossible. *Any hints on how this solution might be
implemented?* The answer may of course bypass `Gnuplot.py`.

Comment: Very intriguing idea!

Comment: @Alfe: in what do you find this particularly intriguing?

Comment: Up to now I *knew* that I had to convert a Python function into Gnuplot syntax to get it plotted, or to choose samples before opening Gnuplot, thus losing all (or most) of the interactive capabilities (e. g. zooming) of Gnuplot.  Now your question opened my mind to the possibility of doing it otherwise.  That's what I find intriguing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I'm fully answering your question, but you could try executing your python script as a system call within gnuplot passing the argument(s).

For instance, imagine the simple python script `test.py`:

```
import sys

x=float(sys.argv[1])

print x**2
```

which will return the square of the argument when called like this from a shell:

```
:~$ python test.py 2
4.0
:~$ python test.py 3
9.0
:~$ python test.py 4
16.0
```

Now, within gnuplot, turn this into a function:

```
gnuplot> f(x) = real(system(sprintf("python test.py %g", x)))
gnuplot> print f(1)
1.0
gnuplot> print f(2)
4.0
gnuplot> print f(3)
9.0
gnuplot> print f(4)
16.0
```

I added the `real()` so that the string output from the system call is converted to float. This now allows you to use it as a regular gnuplot function. I don't need to mention this will take a lot longer to execute than just `plot x**2`:

```
f(x) = real(system(sprintf("python test.py %g", x)))
plot f(x)
```

[image]

Comment: That’s indeed a very good start, thanks! I’ll try to write a Python function that implements this method, maxing it usable with a single call.

Comment: @Alfe Thanks for the suggestion, I changed it.