# Is there in prod() operator in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, operator-keyword, product

I am beginner with gnuplot and I am trying to plot the following function with gnuplot:

```
f(x) = sum[i=0:x](Pi[j=0:i](x+j-3))
```

where by Pi I mean the product operator:

```
Pi[j=0:i](x+j-3) = (x+0-3)*(x+1-3)...(x+i-3)
```

How can I write the gnuplot script for the Pi part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if I didn't made mistakes you could use a recursive function:

```
prod(x,n,m) = (n<0) ? 1 : (x+n+m) * prod(x,n-1,m)
f(x) = sum[i=0:int(x)](prod(x,i,-3))
plot [0:3] f(x)
```

[image]

Comment: Much better than mine

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the recipe in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562920/passing-python-functions-to-gnuplot/31576005#31576005) to use external functions, in this case Python. Create the external file `function.py`:

```
import sys
x=float(sys.argv[1])
i=int(sys.argv[2])

p = 1
for j in range(0,i+1):
    p *= x + j - 3

print p
```

Now in gnuplot you can define the following product and sum functions:

```
prod(x,i) = real(system(sprintf("python function.py %g %i", x, i)))

f(x) = sum[i=0:int(x)](prod(x,i))

plot[0:3] f(x)
```

[image]

Note that `x` needs to be integer to be used to define the limits of the summation. Also note that calling external functions is quite slow.